# Send email through phpmailer (email address hosted on Google Apps)

Tags: php, google-apps, phpmailer

I have decided to swtich from the php `mail()` class to `phpMailer`. I have also moved my email address to `Google Apps`.

I have been looking at the PHPMailer examples http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples but none specify the setup with `Google Apps`.

I've tried this too (but it uses `Gmail` **NOT** `Google Apps`) : [Can't send an email using a google apps account with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301213/cant-send-an-email-using-a-google-apps-account-with-phpmailer)

Has anyone acheived this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Gmail` and `Google Apps` as mail host is similar. The answer in [Can't send an email using a google apps account with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5301733/1349295) demonstrates how you use `Google Apps` with `PHPMailer`. Check this page : [GMail and Google Apps as outgoing mail server (SMTP)](http://www.activecollab.com/forums/post/17023/).

Comment: i am trying to use google apps with phpmailer (not gmail) are there certain configurations that need to be made in google apps for this to work?

Comment: the defaults in google apps should work just fine. the only difference in usage with gmail is the username which is `username@gmail.com` while it would be `username@yourdomain.com` for google apps.

Comment: Seemed like the key was to add the SMTP settings and Google account creds. Kudos for the help!